# helm install in kuberneres - Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, eclipse-che

Trying to install Che in Kubernertes:

from: https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/kubernetes-single-user.html

Deploying Che:

```
helm upgrade --install my-che-installation --namespace my-che-namespace -f ./
```

Error:
Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the `-f` - that is normally used for a values file but it is pointing to a whole dir and not a values file. If you take that out and run `helm upgrade --install my-che-installation --namespace my-che-namespace ./` from the suggested path then you get a different error because the dependencies are not built. If you then run `helm dep build .` and try again then it works.

Answer (score 0):

When I see this error the first thing that comes to my mind (and I ran into this many times) are **typos in the command**.

For example when I use `--set` to pass inline values and I leave a whitespace in the assignment:

```
#Error: This command needs 2 arguments
helm upgrade --install -f  <VALUES_FILE_PATH> --set SomeToken= $Token ..

#OK
helm upgrade --install -f  <VALUES_FILE_PATH> --set SomeToken=$Token ..
```

I would also check if the `-f` flag was passed in the right location.